# React Native Android build failed after upgrading 0.51 to 0.64

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, build.gradle

I have updated my react-native project from 0.51.0 to the latest version. After updating everything clearly as mentioned in the documentation, I am getting below error when I try to run my app. I already clean gradlew and .gradle/caches several times

> 1- cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android

Here is build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 20
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to run the android app clearly but It gives the below error. I tried invalidating caches/restart too. But that was not helped me.

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Android resource linking failed   /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:11: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf) not found.
>        /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:11: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintStart_toStartOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf) not found.
>        /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:11: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toTopOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf) not found.
>        /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:23: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf) not found.
>        /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:23: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintStart_toEndOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf) not found.
>        /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:23: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toTopOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf) not found.
>        /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:45: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf) not found.
>        /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7f6257c2b8e43de19785244bfe890f9d/res/layout/dg_fragment_region_select.xml:45: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf (aka com.xxx.ppm:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf) not found.
>        error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: I faced same issue, resolved it by downgrade gradle version to 3.3.2. Hope this helps you too

Comment: Unfortunatelly that was not helped me @SandipSingh

Comment: Hello @doganilker, did you manage to find a solution for this? im hitting this issue as well.